# How to print files except certain files in Shell

Tags: shell

I can use below shell to print filename starting with aaa.

ls -l aaa*

But how can I exclude certain pattern to print using ls command or if clause ?

Suppose I want to print all files except filename that contains expr.

[FileList]

aaa.out

expr01

aexpr02

find.sh

ch.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -l aaa* | grep -v "expr"
```

Think of the "-v" as negati**v**e search.

Comment: Except if instead of `expr` you actually want to exclude something like `"-rw-"`.  Perhaps you're then better off using Awk, but beware of all the grave pitfalls of [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Oh I didn't know that this feature, I've just checked it. thanks for your help !!! : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use --hide option in ls command

that is

```
ls --hide='pattern'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is Bash, you can use [extended globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing).

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(expr)
```

You can turn off extended globbing again with `shopt -u extglob`.